# how to pass slot value in sample utterence in alexa skill?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

I am using custom slot in Alexa skill. I have created one slot with pName as slot  name and slot type is **ProductName**.
When I call my intent after open my skill it always goes to unhandled input.
I have followed document for create custom slot but still not getting success.
e.g.// my sample utterance is below :
i have one intent name OnHandQuantityIntent with sample utterance 
**on hand stock for item {pName}**

**User input :** on hand stock for item xyz234
**Alexa response :** inside unhandled intent.

Model :

```
{
"interactionModel": {
    "languageModel": {
        "invocationName": "ebs demo",
        "intents": [
            {
                "name": "AMAZON.FallbackIntent",
                "samples": []
            },
            {
                "name": "AMAZON.CancelIntent",
                "samples": []
            },
            {
                "name": "AMAZON.HelpIntent",
                "samples": []
            },
            {
                "name": "AMAZON.StopIntent",
                "samples": []
            },
            {
                "name": "OnHandQuantityDemoIntent",
                "slots": [
                    {
                        "name": "PName",
                        "type": "Product_Type"
                    }
                ],
                "samples": [
                    "Onhand quantity {PName}",
                    "get onhand quantity for item {PName}",
                    "provide me onhand quantity for {PName}"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "types": [
            {
                "name": "Product_Type",
                "values": [
                    {
                        "id": "AT23808",
                        "name": {
                            "value": "AT23808",
                            "synonyms": [
                                "at23808",
                                "AT23808"
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
    }
}
```

Here is my alexa.js function

```
'use strict';
const Alexa = require('alexa-sdk');
const APP_ID = undefined;
const SKILL_NAME = 'DemoForDirectCall';
const GET_ITEM_MESSAGE = "ITEM DETAIL: ";
const HELP_MESSAGE = 'WE can get real time on hand quantity for Product';
const HELP_REPROMPT = 'What can I help you with?';
const STOP_MESSAGE = 'Goodbye!';



const handlers = {
   'LaunchRequest': function () {
    this.response.speak("Welcome to Demo for direct call");
    this.response.shouldEndSession(false);
    this.emit(':responseReady');
},
'OnHandQuantityDemoIntent': function () {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.event.request));
    var productName = "NONE";
    var intent = this.event.request.intent;
    if(!intent.slots.PName)
        productName = intent.slots.PName.value;
    const speechOutput = "You have entered "+productName;
    this.response.speak(speechOutput);
    this.emit(':responseReady');
 },
 'AMAZON.HelpIntent': function () {
    const speechOutput = HELP_MESSAGE;
    const reprompt = HELP_REPROMPT;
    this.response.speak(speechOutput).listen(reprompt);
    this.emit(':responseReady');
 },
 'AMAZON.CancelIntent': function () {
    this.response.speak(STOP_MESSAGE);
    this.emit(':responseReady');
 },
 'AMAZON.StopIntent': function () {
    this.response.speak(STOP_MESSAGE);
    this.emit(':responseReady');
 },
 'Unhandled': function () {
    console.log("Inside unhandled Intent");
    this.response.speak("Inside Unhandled Intent");
    this.emit(':responseReady');
 },
};

exports.handler = function (event, context, callback) {
const alexa = Alexa.handler(event, context, callback);
alexa.APP_ID = APP_ID;
alexa.registerHandlers(handlers);
alexa.execute();
};
```

User input : Open ebs demo
Alexa Response with welcome message
User Input : onhand quantity for item AT23808
Alexa Response : Inside Unhandled Intnet.

Answer (score 1):

Its going into `Unhandled` because there is no intent handler for `AMAZON.FallbackIntent`. And the user input mentioned is triggering this intent which  ultimately comes as "Unhandled".

**Abbreviations and numbers in Slot values**

When you are dealing with abbreviations like AT or ATZ or XYZ you have to give slot values like this. (try to give more variations)

```
x. y. z. two four seven nine
A. T. Z. one two three four
A. T. two three eight zero eight
```

When testing it in Test Simulator use utterances like

> ask ebs demo on stock for item x. y. z. five three seven

With your interaction model and the changes I mentioned, I got a request generated like this for the above utterance

```
"intent": {
            "name": "OnHandQuantityDemoIntent",
            "confirmationStatus": "NONE",
            "slots": {
                "PName": {
                    "name": "PName",
                    "value": "XYZ537",
...
```

Also, it will be a good idea to change your invocation name from `ebs` to `e. b. s.`

Comment: Thanks for quick response, It is working but still facing issue sometimes it jumps to inside Unhandle Intent and some times skill not found. May be it is not a coding bug. I have noticed Alexa speaks "Zero" as "O" sometimes. How to handle that?

Comment: Which is the intent mapped when it jumps to unhandled intent

Comment: ask e. b. s. demo to get onhand quantity for item A. T. two three eight zero eight     -    Not working
ask e. b. s. demo and get onhand quantity for item x. y. z. five three seven one   -  working
Actullay I want to call direct intent if user provide some specific values like this.

Comment: e.g.// open ebs demo and provide me on hand stock for AT23808 OR
give me on hand stock for AT23808 from ebs demo

Comment: can you add some more slot value variations like A. T. one two three four

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume i have to input product from  the user. So product is my slot and productType will be my slot Type.

```
Slot Types: productType 
  Values: washing machine.
product is of type: ProductType

Sample Utterance: My {product} is not working.

User input: My washing machine is not working.
```

This should work.

In Your case i guess you need to add sample values for your ProductName which is alpha numeric. Then it will surely work.
All the best.

Comment: I have added alpha numeric and i have also tested with only alphabet but still not any result.

Comment: @user3256309 can u share your json object so that i can check can help you with?

Comment: Hello Suneet ,  I have updated my question with code please help me to resolve the issue?

Comment: add A. T. two three eight zero eight as your value for productType. It will work. As your dealing with letters and when pronouncing it clubs as word so. Read this for more details https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/choose-the-invocation-name-for-a-custom-skill.html#cert-invocation-name-req